# How can I modify this WebGL drawImage equivalent so that it doesn't clear pixels drawn beneath transparent images?

Tags: webgl

[I followed this tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html) for recreating `drawImage` for WebGL, but one thing it doesn't cover is the fact that for images with transparent pixels, for example game sprites, everything behind the image rectangle (even where pixels are transparent) gets cleared.

This is probably trivial but I'm completely new to GLSL, here are the shaders:

`fragment`

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
```

`vertex`

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
   gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
   v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
```

How can I modify these to avoid hiding pixels in the frame that have already been rendered when the transparent pixels of a sprite are rendered onto them?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Its hard to find for a beginner because introductory tutorials dont explain a lot of important basics, like the fact that you can use `texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord).a` to get the alpha, or `discard` to not draw the pixel.

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
  float alpha = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord).a;
  if (alpha < 1.0) {
    discard;
  }
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: yes, often people make that settable. Declare a uniform `uniform float alphaTest;` and then make the test `if (alpha < alphaTest)`. That way you can set it. It's common to set it lower.  Another think you can do is set turn on blending. Sorry it's buried but blending is covered in [this tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-texture.html)